# Numpy issue with converting list into array

Tags: python, numpy

To begin this topic off I've created a stock market environment that a function can return its observation through this function. The field 'df' is a pandas instance loaded from csv file and I am returning a step (row) of the data frame to get the data which return its value on the data sheet. My issue is when I set the data to the observation field it return different values then the data sheet.

```
    def _next_observation(self):
        observation = [
            self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Open'],
            self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'High'],
            self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Low'],
            self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Close'],
            self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Volume'],
            self.account_quantity
        ]

        # Add Indicators
        if self.indicators != None:
            for _ in range(len(self.indicators)):
                observation.append(self.df.loc[self.current_step, self.indicators[_][0]])


        print(observation) # Print normally
        
        self.observation = np.array(observation) # Hmmmmmm

        print(self.observation) # Print strangly

        exit(1)


        return self.observation
```

The first observation in the step return instance of this data which is incorrect is listed below.

```
[ 5.17610000e-01  5.17810000e-01  5.15010000e-01  5.15370000e-01
  5.18581850e+06  0.00000000e+00  3.76286621e+01  5.15838144e-01
 -1.86428571e-05]
```

I have narrow the issue down to a line of code.

The correct data is presented as a list not numpy array below

```
[0.51761, 0.51781, 0.51501, 0.51537, 5185818.5, 0, 37.62866206258322, 0.5158381442961018, -1.864285714292535e-05]
```

If anyone has any tips of how to solve this issue please let me know I don't understand why this is happening. I usually don't ask for help but this is the first. I also have a Agent (A2C) that keep returning 0 as it action and I believe the data is to blame.

Sincerely, Richard

Comment: Those are the same.  The array just uses scientific notation for all values.  It does this when the range of values is large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is just in exponential notation but identical. To suppress exponential notation in numpy you can do the following:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(supress = True)
```

or you can use formatted printing of variables such as:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(f"{item:0.3f}")
```

Comment: Interesting, I still cant force it out of exponential notation even when adding dtypes to the array. Thank you for the information I found out you can supress the issue when it prints by typing ```np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)``` but I need the data to be out of exponetial notaion so I can feed the tensor model

Comment: ah yes that wouldn't change as it is still a float. Updating my answer

Comment: RIght...as I see you wrote as well. This should not affect what you feed the tensor model since it is just how the number is being displayed. The number itself is a float.

Comment: Interesting enough the model still predict the same action hmmmm I will have to save that issue for a different form thank you @Dan Boschen for the useful information!